# What are M4 & T4 protocol of Hearing aid compatibility of GSM & CDMA model of iPhone 4?

Tags: iphone

Saw this in Wikipedia (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iphone_4):

**Hearing aid compatibility**

```
GSM
3G 850/1,900 MHz M4, T4
2G 850 MHz M3, T3
2G 1,900 MHz M2, T3

CDMA M4, T4
```

So what do M4, T4, M2, ...  mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you see a **M3**, **M4**, **T3** or **T4** on the box then the phone has been designated as HAC compliant.

**About the T**

> "T" refers to the phone's coupling ability and is intended for use
>   with hearing aids in the telecoil mode. The higher the "T" number the
>   more likely you will be able to use the phone with your hearing aid on
>   the telecoil setting. A telecoil is a small device that is built into
>   some hearing aids for use with the telephone as well as assistive
>   listening devices. To use the telecoil, generally either the hearing
>   aid is switched to the "T" position or a button on the hearing aid is
>   pushed to select the telecoil program. The telecoil picks up magnetic
>   fields generated by telephones and converts these fields into sound.
>   Telecoils are particularly useful for telephone communication because
>   they permit the volume control of a hearing aid to be turned up
>   without creating feedback or "whistling," and background noise can be
>   reduced especially when using cell phones in noisy places. That is why
>   hearing aid phones are important. They give you the ability to control
>   and process sound.

source: [betterhearing.org](http://www.betterhearing.org/hearingpedia/hearing-aid-compatible-cell-phones)

**About the difference between M and T**

> An "M" rating measures compatibility with acoustic hearing aids while
>   a "T" rating measures compatibility with induction hearing aids. So
>   the higher the number (e.g., M3, M4 etc.) the more compatible the
>   handset. Generally, handsets rated "M3" or "T3" by ANSI or better are
>   considered compliant with FCC requirements. Acoustic Hearing Aids
>   M3-rating indicates the handset has satisfied the ANSI standard
>   M4-rating indicates the handset has exceeded the ANSI standard
>
> Induction Hearing Aids T3-rating indicates the handset has satisfied
>   the ANSI standard T4-rating indicates the handset has exceeded the
>   ANSI standard

source: [uscellular.com](http://www.uscellular.com/uscellular/services/hearing-aid.jsp)